# scala flatten List(List(List(String, List(String, String)

Tags: scala

after pattern matching BasicDBobject from mongo casbas i get something Like that:

```
val arr = List(Some(None), 
               List(List(Some(None),
                         Some(None),
                         Some("54c22f3369702d7fdb8c0100"),
                         Some(None),
                         Some(None),
                         Some(None),
                         Some(None)),
                    List(Some(None), 
                         Some(None),
                         Some("54c22f3369702d7fdb8c0100"),
                         Some(None),
                         Some(None),
                         Some(None), 
                         Some(None)),
                    List(Some(None),
                         Some(None),
                         Some("54c22f3369702d7fdb8c0100"),
                         Some(None),
                         Some(None),
                         Some(None),
                         Some(None))),
                    Some(None))
```

I need flatten this in `List(Some(none), Some(string) ..)`  in one list. How i can did this?

example what i need from arr:

```
    List( Some("54c22f3369702d7fdb8c0100"), 
Some("54c22f3369702d7fdb8c0100"),  
Some("54c22f3369702d7fdb8c0100") )
```

I get arr by this code:

```
val subjectUsers = x.map {
        case ("entries", y: BasicDBList) => y(0) match {
          case entries: BasicDBList => entries.toList map {
            case z: BasicDBObject => z.toList map {
              case ("type", "subscribe") => Some(z("subject_id"))
              case ("info", v: BasicDBObject) => Some(v("user"))
              case _ => Some(None)
            }
            case _ => Some(None)
          }
        }
        case _ => Some(None)
      }.toList
```

I need only List(String) like

```
List( Some("54c22f3369702d7fdb8c0100"), Some("54c22f3369702d7fdb8c0100"))
```

Comment: Can you give the desired output for your example list? I'm not clear what it should be.

Comment: Now we have a contradiction. You say you want the `Some(None)` first, but your example output doesn't have it. Can you describe what you want? do you want to collect all subsublist entries that are Some(string)?

Comment: Also, the top level list has an unhelpful type. Do you really get Some(None) followed by a List? And the subLists are odd types too...

Comment: I think the real problem is your `Some(None)` in your code... I think you mean just `None`

Comment: It not a problem, i can change Some(none) to None, but how i remove List(List(List())) ?

Comment: What I mean was that if you had a better/cleaner set of types, you would find it easier to manipulate the result., If you may or may not have something, you should have Some(that-thing) and None (that is, an Option type), whereas you have that-thing, and Some(none), which is... well, confused, basically. You have an answer that works for you, great, but really its an answer to the wrong question (IMO)

Comment: I understand you, but at previous selecor i can use List ( ... ).flatten - and it works only when all element in Some(). i think i have rly wrong start and at future try to fix it, ty for advices! P.S both: Some and None are optional?

Comment: Some(x) and None are two subclasses of Option, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a truly arbitrary structure you could use [shapeless' everything combinator](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/d59463a0c093a21345754226702cbd807015b6ca/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/sybclass.scala) to collect all the `Some[String]`s in a type-safe way. That will only work if you have all the type information at compile time though. If you want to do this based on runtime type the best approach is probably a recursive function that pattern matches:

```
def extractSomeStrings(a: Any): List[Some[String]] = a match {
  case l: List[_] => l flatMap extractSomeStrings
  case None => List()
  case Some(x) => x match {
    case s: String => List(Some(s))
  }
}
```

That will (deliberately) throw `MatchError` if the list contains anything other than `List`s, `None`s and `Some[String]`s - if you have other cases you can add `case`s to handle them.

Comment: [error]       case s: String => Some(s)
compilation error:  type mismatch

Comment: Ah yes, forgot that we need the outer `List`.